# Get Back Lost Audio

Tags: obs-studio

In OBS while recording some online lectures I added a Noise Gate filter but with wrong settings due to which the audio was not recorded properly is there any way to get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if the gate was closed.

Any sound that doesn't pass the gate doesn't reach the recording.
Unless you've time for a sound check, gates etc are best dealt with after the fact.